# How To transfer session after login to other browser

Tags: .net, firefox, xulrunner

How to transfer the login session between Firefox browser

i have made a .net desktop application that opens Firefox browser in it as the user login i want to transfer the session after login to the Firefox browser from the desktop application installed on the computer.

The basic requirement is hide the login details from the users

Comment: As far as I know Firefox shares cookies for all instances from a given profile. You can check it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Multiple_Firefox_Profiles